# Is It Possible To Break Up Rendering Users By Their Attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on developing an admin dashboard for a bloglike application.

Currently I display all the users I have to the admin as follows:

```
<h3>All Users</h3>
<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>
```

Admins are a type of user, with the attribute :admin set to true. The same is true of supervisors, who have the attribute :supervisor set to true.

Is there any way I can tweak this code so instead of displaying all users to the admin its divided up more like:

```
Admins:
  #list of admins
Supervisors:
  #list of supervisors
Users:
  #list of remaining users
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just group them in your controller.

```
@admins = User.where(admin: true)
@users = User.where(admin: false)
```

Then

```
<%= render @admins %>
<%= render @users %>
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for your help! This solved it :)

Comment: @Andrew Friendly advice, try to do more research before asking questions. :)